# AddForce method doesn't work when it's called by a button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a basic character controller script which has a jump method which looks like this:

```
void Jump()
{
    rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0,jumpHeight),ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    Debug.Log("Jump method called");
}
```

The problem with this is that it works fine when I call this method in `FixedUpdate()` but if I try to call it by a button, the method gets called but the `AddForce()` line does not do anything at all. I also tried different ways to make the player jump like using `rb.velocity`. It still doesn't work. Do I need to call it in `FixedUpdate()`? What's the reason behind this?

Comment: Have you verified that `jump` is actually being called?

Comment: how are you calling it from a button ? did you assign the jump function to the OnClick method in the button ? or via script? check if spellings are correct of the button.

Comment: It should work without calling it from `FixedUpdate`. What you should check: One, whether or not `Jump` is actually called. Two, maybe the force is too small? If the force you apply is lower than gravity, the object will not move. Three, is there friction on the way? Unity uses realistic physics model, if your object has friction with some other object, it will cancel your impulse out.

Comment: I believe physics operations like this *do* belong in FixedUpdate.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, debug line shows up in the console.

Comment: @joel64 I call it by assigning the method to the OnClick method in the button.

Comment: @YuraNudelman  I can verify that the method is being called but I don't think the force is too small because I added a force which is over 3 millions in play mode (not multiplied with time) and still didn't move at all.

Comment: Are you using Rigidbody2D? Do you have the rigidbody2d attached to your object? What values are set in the Rigidbody?  If you want to call the jump with UI button, using FixedUpdate or Update is not relevant.

Comment: Yes, I do. It is attached to the game object and here are the settings of it:(https://imgur.com/a/JzAITuG)

Comment: @No-LifeDev How do you set the `Jump()` function to `OnClick` method on the button? Can you give me a picture of the Button component? your script works for me.

Comment: I just drag the gameObject which has the script on it. It looks like this at the end. (https://imgur.com/a/MOxaFfq). And as I said, method does get called. Console writes the line as expected but the player doesn't move.